# Where I can download "Principe de concentration-compacité en calcul des variations"

Tags: reference-request

Recently, I read  [**Orbital stability of standing waves for some nonlinear Schrödinger equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01403504). I have some question about the concentration compactness method, so I want to read the Lions' *Principe de concentration-compacité en calcul des variations*. But I can't find it, where I can download it. Or there are some substitute. Thanks

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://www.numdam.org/article/SEDP_1982-1983____A14_0.pdf

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Yes, thanks.

Comment: I just typed *Principe de concentration-compacite en calcul des variations* on Google and got it ! Cheers and have fun !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Whether it has English version ?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no. This is a teaching material from the most prestigious French school.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the reference in the paper by Cazenave and Lions is for Lions' article MR0653747 (or Zbl 0485.49005), which is not the one which Claude Leibovici posted, as evidenced by the number of pages (which is different from 4).

To download the refereed paper, you may visit https://www.academie-sciences.fr/en/Transmettre-les-connaissances/comptes-rendus-de-l-academie-des-sciences-numerisees-sur-le-site-de-la-bibliotheque-nationale-de-france.html and access the pages 261-264 of the 15 February 1982 volume of the Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des sciences.

Comment: It's been a long time since the problem is asked. Although I am no longer interested in it, I still appreciate your detailed answer.